# Isotope grid checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-isotope

I am using the Isotope lib to filter out items but I was wondering if there was a way to add check boxes also to enable like mutlple selections?

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate where I am at:

https://jsfiddle.net/arkau0gg/

My Scripts file looks like this:

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#container'),
      $filterLinks = $('#filters a');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    filter: '.red'
  });

  $filterLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return;
    }

    $filterLinks.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // get selector from data-filter attribute
    selector = $this.data('filter');

    $container.isotope({
      filter: selector
    });


  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cycle on checkboxes and take data-filter attribute for those checked.
Like this javascript:

```
$(function(){
  var $container = $('#container'),
      $filterLinks = $("input[type='checkbox']");

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    filter: '.red'
  });

  $filterLinks.change(function(){
    var selector= '';
    $filterLinks.each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
        if(selector != '') selector += ',';
        selector += $(this).data('filter');
      }
    });

    if(selector){
      $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
      });
    }


  });

});
```

Try here: https://jsfiddle.net/rbkctham/

Comment: Hey thats awesome, the only is that it kills off the other sorting too